# django : using Q objects

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset, django-q

I have these 2 queries :

```
gifts = Products.objects \
    .filter(entry_query,in_stock__icontains='A-in') \
    .filter(~Q(title__icontains='Not Found'))
```

and

```
gifts1 = Products.objects \
    .filter(('city__name__iregex', 'Delhi'),in_stock__icontains='A-in') \
    .filter(~Q(title__icontains='Not Found'))
```

If I do `gifts = gifts | gifts1` I get the following error:

> error user-defined function raised exception

If i use Q objects like this:

```
gifts = Products.objects \
    .filter((Q(entry_query) & Q(in_stock__icontains='A-in')) | Q(('city__name__iregex', 'Delhi'),in_stock__icontains='A-in') ) \
    .filter(~Q(title__icontains = 'Not Found'))
```

I again get the same error

Here entry query is

```
(OR: ('title__iregex', u'bag'), ('description__iregex', u'bag'),('source_website_url__iregex', u'bag'))
```

Can someone please tell me where am I going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in the first approach is because gifts1 and gifts are already [QuerySets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries#chaining-filters) (try typeof(gifts)), so you cannot use | between them. It is like if you were using 'hi'|'goodbye'. You only use | for [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

What you did the second time was almost correct, except the syntax: use | for OR and & for AND. The comma does not provide any logical operation on the Q, leading to a different argument on the filter, leading to an error.

Notice that both using & and joining filters are equivalent in Django (or are supposed to be), but your first approach of getting gift and gift1 as different QuerySets and evaluating them is different: that approach leads to two accesses (hits) to the database, while joining filters or Q objects in a single filter [only hits it once](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy).

As a rule of thumb, you should minimize the number of hits to the db.

Hope this helps